# Populating radio buttons and JavaScript object properties with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I have some form elements which names and id's correspond to the names of some customly defined JavaScript objects and some of the keys of a JSON data.

How can I populate the form and the objects from JSON provided form names are not known and the only link is the common name of the form element, object and JSON key? JSON may contain other, non form and object related data.

In the example below the difficulty was to figure out how to get the name of and subsequently the corresponding radio button. Are there any more efficient non-iterative ways to do that?

I used eval() to reference the objecs. Besides not being the best way, I will get an error if the JSON key evaluates to false, i.e. there is not an object name with a particular JSON key name. As form elements and JavaScript objects mirror each other completely, I used a DOM element check before impementing the eval() method, is there any other way to check if an object with a particular name exists?

```js
// JavaScript objects declaration
var nonform = {objName: "nonform"};
var lorem = {objName: "lorem"};
var ipsum = {objName: "ipsum"};
var dolor = {objName: "dolor"};
var sit = {objName: "sit"};
var amet = {objName: "amet"};
var consectetur = {objName: "consectetur"};
 
var json={
"nonform": "some nonform data",
"lorem": "lorem input text",
"ipsum":"ipsum input text",
"dolor": 1,
"sit":"sit input text",
"amet":2,
"consectetur": "sed" 
}

function displayObj (){
var str = "";
str += JSON.stringify(nonform) + "<br>";
str += JSON.stringify(lorem) + "<br>";
str += JSON.stringify(ipsum) + "<br>";
str += JSON.stringify(dolor) + "<br>";
str += JSON.stringify(sit) + "<br>";
str += JSON.stringify(amet) + "<br>";
str += JSON.stringify(consectetur);
document.getElementById("objects").innerHTML = str;
}

function jsonToForm(json) { // populates form elements and objects with JSON data
 for (var x in json) { // JSON iteration
  var id = x; // in my original code x has to be processed to match form and object names
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if (element) { // if JSON key corresponds to a non radio button (unique id) form element
   element.value = json[x]; // updates form values
   eval(id).val = json[x]; // updates object values
  } else if (document.getElementsByName(id)[0]) { // for radio buttons the name attribute is used as JSON key won't match separate radio button id's. NodeList[0] used instead of NodeList as some non radio button DOM elements matched the JSON key in my original code.
   var radios = document.getElementsByName(id);
   for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { // radio button iteration
    if (radios[i].value == json[x]) {
     radios[i].checked=true;
     eval(id).val = json[x];
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 }
displayObj();
}

window.onload = displayObj();
```

```css
input, select {
 margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" id="lorem" name="lorem">
 <input type="text" id="ipsum" name="ipsum">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" id="dolor_0" name="dolor" value="0">
  -0-</label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" id="dolor_1" name="dolor" value="1">
  -1-</label>
</form>
<hr>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="sit" name="sit">
 <label>
  <input type="radio" id="amet_0" name="amet" value="0">
  -0-</label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" id="amet_1" name="amet" value="1">
  -1-</label>
 <label>
  <input type="radio" id="amet_2" name="amet" value="2">
  -2-</label>
 <select id="consectetur" name="consectetur">
  <option value="adipiscing">adipiscing</option>
  <option value="elit">elit</option>
  <option value="sed">sed</option>
  <option value="eiusmod ">eiusmod </option>
 </select>
</form>
<hr>
<div id="objects"> 
</div>
<hr>
<input type="button" value="JSON to form and obj" onclick="jsonToForm(json)">
```

Comment: `var value = document.querySelectorAll("[name=' + id + ']:checked")`

Comment: @ BillPull isn't your query selection (without the checked pseudoclass)  equivalent to document.getElementsByName(id)? In either case, I did not manage to set the value by these references.